# Why does creating a new dataframe using cbind automatically convert a numeric column into factor?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have `L`:

```
   Var1 Freq
2  1103    6
6  1107   10
10 1112    7
21 1125    6
24 1129   10
31 1137    5
```

and `pct`:

```
head(pct)
[1] 0.806 0.706 0.781 0.800 0.655 0.844
```

`pct` is initially numeric, not a factor:

```
str(pct)
num [1:68] 0.806 0.706 0.781 0.8 0.655 0.844
```

However, once I combine `L` and `pct` together with

```
pct_by <- as.data.frame(cbind(as.vector(L$Var1), pct))
```

I see that this new dataframe `pct_by` contains `pct` as factor, as shown below:

```
str(pct_by
'data.frame':   68 obs. of  2 variables:
$ V1: Factor w/ 68 levels "1103","1107",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ pct: Factor w/ 41 levels "0.375","0.529",..: 34 19 29 33 10 37 27 9 12 11 ...
```

Why is this? How can I change `pct_by$pct` so that is numeric, as it originally was, instead of being a Factor?

Comment: Don't `cbind` at all. This is a bad habbit that people seem to pick up from old tutorials or something. Just use `pct_by <- data.frame(L$Var1, pct)`. The problem is that cbind will prefer to return a matrix and matrixes can only hold one data.type.

Comment: @MrFlick Your comment looks like an answer to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `cbind` at all. This is a bad habit that people seem to pick up from old tutorials or something. Just use:

```
pct_by <- data.frame(L$Var1, pct)
```

The problem is that `cbind` will prefer to return a matrix and matrices can only hold one data type. If one of those variables is a string, they will all be turned into strings and then converted to factors when placed in a data.frame.